# How do I check if my MVC session expired, using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have my web.config set apropriately and it works fine but only when the user does a httpPost it recognizes that it should redirect:

```
  <system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="5" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login"></forms>
</authentication>
```

I have this code set in my _Layout:

```
var _redirectUrl = '@Url.Action("Logout", "Login")';
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, request, settings, xhr, props, jqXHR) {
            if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                window.location.href = _redirectUrl;
            }
        });
```

**jqXHR.status returns undefined in my browser debuger, I also tried props.status and still get undefined. Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A request to a timed-out session will result in a http status 302 (Found), that results in a redirect that is transparent. jQuery therefore does not handle this automatically. You could have the server return a http status 401 (Unauthorized) instead of the redirect. Here is an article with code you can copy to do that:

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2014/02/gracefully-handle-mvc-user-session-expiration-in-javascript/

Comment: I **am** using 401, and tried to use the xhr.status === 401 as the article says but I still get undefined for xhr.status.